# Unable to register node "node-name" with API server: Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kubernetes 1.13.2 on bare metals (No Provider).

I already have a master and a worker node set up while ago, but now my new worker node cannot join to the cluster and receives  "Unauthorized" message when it tries to register

I have renewed my token on my master, and created a new join command. But still getting "Unauthorized" response upon joining

After sending **kubeadm join ...** command, it times out

```
[patchnode] Uploading the CRI Socket information "/var/run/dockershim.sock" to the Node API object "node-name" as an annotation
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the condition
```

and here is what I get in **journalctl -u kubelet**

```
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: I0422 20:31:13.399059   18567 kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: I0422 20:31:13.404930   18567 kubelet_node_status.go:72] Attempting to register node node-name
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.406863   18567 kubelet_node_status.go:94] Unable to register node "node-name" with API server: Unauthorized
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.407096   18567 event.go:203] Server rejected event '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"node-name.1597fce5edba5ee6", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Initializers:(*v1.Initializers)(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:""}, InvolvedObject:v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"node-name", UID:"node-name", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"NodeHasSufficientMemory", Message:"Node node-name status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory", Source:v1.EventSource{Component:"kubelet", Host:"node-name"}, FirstTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xbf27bf9d2c75d6e6, ext:897526251, loc:(*time.Location)(0x71d3440)}}, LastTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xbf27bfa05821f203, ext:13556483910, loc:(*time.Location)(0x71d3440)}}, Count:8, Type:"Normal", EventTime:v1.MicroTime{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, Series:(*v1.EventSeries)(nil), Action:"", Related:(*v1.ObjectReference)(nil), ReportingController:"", ReportingInstance:""}': 'Unauthorized' (will not retry!)
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.409745   18567 event.go:203] Server rejected event '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"node-name.1597fce5edba8b6c", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Initializers:(*v1.Initializers)(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:""}, InvolvedObject:v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"node-name", UID:"node-name", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"NodeHasSufficientPID", Message:"Node node-name status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID", Source:v1.EventSource{Component:"kubelet", Host:"node-name"}, FirstTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xbf27bf9d2c76036c, ext:897537648, loc:(*time.Location)(0x71d3440)}}, LastTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0xbf27bfa0582242b8, ext:13556504573, loc:(*time.Location)(0x71d3440)}}, Count:8, Type:"Normal", EventTime:v1.MicroTime{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, Series:(*v1.EventSeries)(nil), Action:"", Related:(*v1.ObjectReference)(nil), ReportingController:"", ReportingInstance:""}': 'Unauthorized' (will not retry!)
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.476603   18567 kubelet.go:2266] node "node-name" not found
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.576911   18567 kubelet.go:2266] node "node-name" not found
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.630766   18567 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.631616   18567 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:444: Failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized
Apr 22 20:31:13 node-name kubelet[18567]: E0422 20:31:13.632799   18567 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:453: Failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized
```

Comment: It seems authentication/authorization issue, check if token is correctly set and right role is assigned with token

Comment: Yes tokens seems fine with valid expiration date. Here is an example of a newly token I just created but still get unauthorized message 

hy9fyn.z4wdqa9jg6xehrn2   23h         2019-05-03T20:38:26Z   authentication,signing   <none>        system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token

BTW What do you mean by the right role? (This is a join token created by kubeadm)

Comment: Have you resolved issue? If not can you provide commands how you renewed token and using kubeadm join

Comment: Yes, I have resolved my problem by setting up again my master and worker nodes. During this process I have noticed the docker version was difference between master and worker nodes, and also the kubernetes version had a minor version difference (the last digit of the version). My best guess is the mismatched versions of docker and kubernetes itself could be the cause of the issue

Comment: Have you reinstalled Docker and Kubernetes to have the same versions on both machines ?

Comment: It was almost two years ago, but yes...I suppose we reinstalled the docker and kubernetes on machines and matched their versions

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by Docker and/or Kubernetes version mismatch between Kubernetes nodes.
The problem was resolved after reinstalling Docker and Kubernetes to the correct versions.

Kubernetes `version skew support policy` describes the maximum version skew supported between various Kubernetes components. For more information, see the [version-skew-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/) documentation.

The Kubernetes [release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/CHANGELOG) list which versions of Docker are compatible with that version of Kubernetes.
For example in the [CHANGELOG-1.13.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.13.md#external-dependencies) you can find validated docker versions for Kubernetes 1.13.